# How to authenticate NTAG213 with ACR122U

Tags: authentication, nfc, mifare, apdu, acr122

I'm using an ACR122U reader with an NTAG213 card. The card is password (reading and writing) protected with the password `52 84 00 08`. What are the APDU commands I should run to authenticate the card and also to read pages 30 and 31 of it once authenticated?

I know with the MiFare 1k I could load the password and authenticate a sector, but I'm not sure how authentication works with the NTAG213 cards with the ACR122U readers.

Answer (score 4):

With the ACR122U you would need to send direct commands to the PN532 NFC controller chip inside the reader in order to exchange such low-level commands. For instance, you could use the `InCommunicateThru` command to send a raw command to the tag:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------------+-----------+-----+
| CLA | INS | P1  | P2  | Lc           | DATA      | Le  |
| FF  | 00  | 00  | 00  | 2 + len(CMD) | D4 42 CMD | --  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------------+-----------+-----+
```

That way, you could send the password authentication command (`PWD_AUTH`) to the tag:

```
FF 00 00 00  07  D4 42  1B  52 84 00 08
                        --  -----------
                        |   |
                        |   \-> password
                        \-> command: PWD_AUTH
```

The response to this command should be something like

```
D5 43 00  PACK  90 00
```

Similarly, you can send a `READ` command to read any page:

```
FF 00 00 00  04  D4 42  30  XX
```

where `XX` is the 1-byte page address.

Note that the read command should also work using the (more robust?) `InDataExchange` command:

```
FF 00 00 00  05  D4 40 01  30  XX
```

Comment: I'm using the ACR122U tool from ACS to send commands to the NTAG 213. After I send the authentication command and I try to read a read/write protected page, this is what happens:
< FF 00 00 00 07 D4 42 30 04 
> D5 43 02 90 00 

I can't seem to read anything at all that is authentication protected. Should I be using another program to communicate with the ACR122u?

Comment: @KaZaaV2 That's odd. Status code 0x02 indicates a CRC error (which should not really happen since the PN532 automatically handles the CRC). Did you also try the InDataExchange version of the command?

Comment: @KaZaaV2 Also: Did authentication work? I.e. did you receive a response in the form `D5 43 00  xx xx  90 00`? And what value do you get back in response to the APDU `FF 00 00 00  06  D4 06 63 02 63 03`?

Comment: @KaZaaV2 Sorry, I just realized that I did not set Lc to the correct value in the last two APDU commands. Did you fix that yourself? If not, please try the commands in my updated answer.

Comment: Yes I tried the InDataExchange version of the command and got the same thing.

I tried the stuff you said above and this is what I got:
ACR122U APDU Command
`< FF 00 00 00 07 D4 42 1B 88 04 00 00 
> D5 43 00 00 00 90 00 `

ACR122U APDU Command
`< FF 00 00 00 06 D4 42 06 63 02 63 03 
> D5 43 01 90 00 `

ACR122U APDU Command
`< FF 00 00 00 07 D4 42 30 04 
> D5 43 02 90 00` 

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake. Meant to post:
ACR122U APDU Command
`< FF 00 00 00 06 D4 06 63 02 63 03` 
`> D5 07 80 80 90 00 `

Comment: @KaZaaV2 Okay, the latter means automatic CRC is enabled in both directions, which is good. Did you also try the updates I posted in my answer? (I.e. the one that fixes the Lc fvalue of the APDU commands.)

Comment: I tried it with the updated value you provided and got basically the same thing:
ACR122U APDU Command
`< FF 00 00 00 04 D4 42 30 04 `

ACR122U APDU Command
`< FF 00 00 00 05 D4 40 01 30 04 `
`> D5 41 13 90 00 `
`> D5 43 02 90 00 `

Comment: Funny enough, on a card that isn't read/write protected with a password it works fine:
ACR122U APDU Command
`< FF 00 00 00 04 D4 42 30 04 `
`> D5 43 00 54 69 63 6B 65 54 69 6E 67 20 45 76 65 6E 74 73 90 00 `

Comment: @KaZaaV2 Could it be that you deselect and reselect the tag between authentication and reading (in that case the authentication state would be lost)?

Comment: Well I never touched the card after I put in on and I also entered the commands you suggested  one after the other so I'm not sure how that deselect may even happen.

Comment: @KaZaaV2 Since I don't know the tool that you are using I can't tell how it might work, but if it closes the connection in between the two commands, this would explain your results.

Comment: I'm using the ACS Scripting Tool that comes with the ACR122u. Is there a tool you can suggest for me to use instead?

Comment: I used the tool here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X7jvK_2LRSI and it works. When I take you commands and authenticate in another APDU, Authentication works . However, when I try to read a block that's password protected using this command: FF 00 00 00 05 D4 40 01 30 XX, I get this response: D5 43 02 90 00 Oddly enough, if i launch the tool and authenticate, then close it and launch another APDU and just try to read without sending the authentication command, it will read the blocks once I don't unplug the ACR122U. Why is this happening?

Comment: I am also struggling with this and what I found out so far: `InDataExchange` / 0x40 does not work for some native NTAG21x commands (`GET_VERSION` / 0x60, `PWD_AUTH` / 0x1B - no response from the device), but does for others (`WRITE` / 0xA2). But using the scripting tool and `InCommunicateThru` / 0x42 they do work. Now I'm trying to get them also working when using a .NET `SmartCardConnection`...

Comment: ...and now got it working also using .NET - my mistake was that I supplied a (correct) `Le`. If I omit that (as in Michaels example) it did work.