# Authenticate NTAG215 with ACR122U

Tags: c#, nfc, apdu, pcsc, acr122

I have an ACR122U reader and several NTAG215 cards,and then I use C#、PCSC sharp to develop it.
I want to set a password and authenticate it,I think the default key is "00 00 00 00" or "FF FF FF FF",and PACK is "00 00".
So I changed the AUTH0 from FFh to 40h, so Page 64 ~ 132 should be password protected.
Then I want to authenticate page 64 and write something into it, but I have problem with authenticate this step.

The following is my code

```
using (var ctx = ContextFactory.Instance.Establish(SCardScope.System))
{
    using (var isoReader = new IsoReader(ctx, connReader, SCardShareMode.Shared, SCardProtocol.Any, false))
    {
        string defaultKey = "FF FF FF FF";
        string[] key = defaultKey.Split(" ");
        byte[] load_keys = new byte[4];
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = key.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            load_keys[count] = Convert.ToByte(key[i], 16);
            count++;
        }
        //0x1B, load_keys[0], load_keys[1], load_keys[2], load_keys[3]
        byte[] auth = { 0xD4, 0x42, 0x1B, load_keys[0], load_keys[1], load_keys[2], load_keys[3] };
        var read = new CommandApdu(IsoCase.Case4Short, isoReader.ActiveProtocol)
        {
            CLA = 0xFF,
            INS = 0x00,
            P1 = 0x00,
            P2 = 0x00,
            Le = 0x07,
            Data = auth
        };
        var rsp_read = isoReader.Transmit(read);
        txtLog.Text += $"Authenticate Response  ( SW1 : {Convert.ToString(rsp_read.SW1, 16).PadLeft(2, '0').ToUpper()} ,  SW2 : {Convert.ToString(rsp_read.SW2, 16).PadLeft(2, '0').ToUpper()}  )" + br;
        
        var data_read = rsp_read.GetData();
        for (int i = 0; i < data_read.Length; i++)
        {
            txtAuth.Text += Convert.ToString(data_read[i], 16).PadLeft(2, '0').ToUpper() + " ";
        }
    }
}
```

The response I got is [ SW1 : 90 ,  SW2 : 00 ] and [ D5 43 01 ]
I thought I should get a response with PACK, but status code is 01.
I don't know which part is wrong, please help me, thanks!

I have read the following articles, but still can't get the answer.

1. [How to authenticate NTAG213 with ACR122U](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44237726/how-to-authenticate-ntag213-with-acr122u?rq=3)
2. [What is the apdu command combination for NTAG 213 tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57609513/what-is-the-apdu-command-combination-for-ntag-213-tag)